# Problems with the same workflow working in two web applications in the same server

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, workflow

I have a workflow to send emails when a new task is created.

I have two web applications on the same server and I'm using that workflow on both.

The problem is that on my default application the workflow is working fine, but on my second application I get the following:

"Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Exception:    at imp.email.emailWorkflow.emailWorkflow.onWorkflowActivated_Invoked(Object sender, ExternalDataEventArgs e)"

This scenario is happening on my Test environment, so I don't have tools such as VS to help me debugg the problem.

On my developing environment I have replicated this scenario and the workflow is working fine in both applications.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe the smtp is not configurated properly on the second web app?

Comment: I don´t think so, since I configured both the same way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out what the problem was, someone changed a few configurations in the users repository. I had a line to get the context, and from that context I took the info I needed, users, Item's description, etc.

After getting the context I would use a parser to retreive each info separatly.

By changing the way the username is displayed, it messed up my parser, in such a way that I would get some null values.

Since my dev environment doesn't use the same user repository, it was hard to track.